# How to set required field to not required after changing payment method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, magento2.4.6

Is there a way to change the state of all billing & shipping address fields from required to not required after selecting the payment method, for example, PayPal? I tried to find some info, and the closest is [Toggle "required/not required" field in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289694/toggle-required-not-required-field-in-checkout) but it's not quite what I need. Appreciate any help. (We are using One Step Checkout from Amasty)